# inconsistencies between the original expression and the result one in apron

Tags: ocaml, polyhedra

I'm using the OCaml interface of the [Apron](https://antoinemine.github.io/Apron/doc/api/ocaml/index.html) library.

When I want to reduce the expression `[| x + y -2 >= 0; x + y > - 3=0|]`, the result of `tab` is `[|-3 + 1 * x + 1 * y >= 0|]`, How can I get the origin expression `x + y - 3 >= 0`?

```
let _ =
  let vx = Var.of_string "x" in
  let vy = Var.of_string "y" in
  let env = Environment.make [||] [|vx;vy|] in
  let c = Texpr1.cst env (Coeff.s_of_int 2) in
  let c' = Texpr1.cst env (Coeff.s_of_int 3) in
  let vx' =  Texpr1.var env vx in
  let vy' = Texpr1.var env vy in
  let texpr = Texpr1.binop Add vx' vy' Real Near in
  let texpr1 = Texpr1.binop Sub texpr c Real Near in
  let texpr2 = Texpr1.binop Sub texpr c' Real Near in
  (* let sum' = Texpr1.(Binop(Sub,x2,Cst c,Int,Near)) in *)
  Format.printf "env = %a@." (fun x -> Environment.print x) env;
  Format.printf "expr = %a@." (fun x -> Texpr1.print x) texpr;
  let cons1 = Tcons1.make texpr1 Lincons0.SUPEQ in
  let cons2 = Tcons1.make texpr2 Lincons0.SUPEQ in

  let tab = Tcons1.array_make env 2 in
  Tcons1.array_set tab 0 cons1;
  Tcons1.array_set tab 1 cons2;
  let abs = Abstract1.of_tcons_array manpk env tab in
  let tab' = Abstract1.to_tcons_array manpk abs in
  Format.printf "tab = %a@." (fun x -> Tcons1.array_print x) tab;
  Format.printf "tab1 = %a@." (fun x -> Tcons1.array_print x) tab'
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that there is no inconsistency as the expressions `-3 + 1 * x + 1 * y >= 0` and `x + y - 3 >= 0` are semantically equivalent.

### Why is the expression printed this way?

You are building a polyhedron (i'm guessing `manpk` refers to the polka manager) and even if it is built using tree-constraints, it is represented internally using linear-constraints. So when you convert it back to tree-constraints, you actually are converting a `Lincons1.earray` to a `Tcons1.earray`, hence the representation as a sum of monoms.

If by "get the origin expression" you mean, make Apron print it in a human friendly way, i suggest you convert your polyhedron to a linear-constraint array (using `to_lincons_array`) and then define your own pretty-printing utility over linear constraints.

Alternatively, you can use the [Apronext](https://github.com/ghilesZ/apronext) library, which is a small wrapper I wrote around the Apron library which provides `pp_print` functions. On your specific example, using `Linconsext.pp_print`, you get: `x+y>=3`. **Disclaimer**, Apronext is neither efficient, nor reliable, nor maintained, so i suggest you dont use it extensively, but only for understanding purposes

Comment: Is there any interface that I can convert a `Tcons1.earray` to `Lincons1.earray`, or vice versa?

Comment: @FrankSheng not that i know, but note that if it is ok to convert a lincons to a tcons, the other way around would require a linearization step.